# spree_products_taxons record creating in RoR: Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I want to create new record in spree_products_taxons table with ActiveRecord (not with pure SQL), but:

```
1.9.3-head :003 > Spree::ProductsTaxon.create(product_id: 666, taxon_id: 777)
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::ProductsTaxon
```

Where am i wrong?

ps. In my schema file:

```
create_table "spree_products_taxons", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "taxon_id"
end
```

Comment: Can you try  Spree::ProductTaxon instead of Spree::ProductsTaxon

Comment: Sorry, I fixed command. I've tried all possible and impossible variants :)))) ProductTaxon not works too, same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
product = Spree::Product.find(666)
taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(777)
product.taxons << taxon
product.save
taxons = product.taxons
```